# Replace an element in an array state (and benefit from ReactJS fast rendering)

Tags: javascript, reactjs

There's a React component which its state is an array of svg elements. In each update only 1 element in this array may change. I want to benefit from wise and fast rendering provided by react. I use the following code to update the state and render.

```
render: function() {
    return (
        <div>
            <svg width={Common.boardWidth} height={Common.boardHeight}>
                {this.state.grid}
            </svg>
        </div>
    );
}

_setNewState: function(index , newState){
    this.setState(function(state){
        return({
            grid: state.grid[index].splice(index,1,newState)
        });
    });
},
```

`_setNewState` is called whenever we receive a new change in the state.

My question :

1.How can I replace an element in the array state to still benefit from fast rendering of React ? Do I benefit from fast rendering of react in the current approach ? or as the array changes, the whole thing will be rendered again ? even those elements which didn't change ?

2.What is the best approach in this case ? do we need to have an array of states instead of state that is an array ?

**Note:** Each element in this array is a SVG element with a unique key.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can easily benefit from efficient rendering if you refactor your code a bit so that each SVG element gets a unique key. This key allows the diffing algorithm to determine if the component is the same. Elements which didn't change won't be rerendered on each `setState` call.

```
render: function() {
    return (
        <div>
            <svg width={Common.boardWidth} height={Common.boardHeight}>
                {this.state.grid.map(function(svg) {
                     return (<svg key={svg.key} ... the rest of the props/>)                    
                }}
            </svg>
        </div>
    );
}
```

Comment: Actually, in `setInitialState` I create the initial array of `SVG`s with unique keys. And in each subsequent update, only 1 specific SVG element is changed.

Comment: then your question is answered isn't it?

Comment: Well, you said "refactor your code ..." , I already mentioned in my code what I said in the comment, so I thought maybe you mean something else.... I already have `SVG` elements with `id`s.

Comment: Yea, you don't have to refactor then, and you're benefitting optimally from Reacts rendering already.